# How to launch Alarm application in Android devices

Tags: android, alarm

As the title denotes: How to launch Alarm application in Android devices?
What is the Intent should be?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What have you already tried? Found any similar posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Clock) from the documentation should have what your looking for. Here's the example they use.

```
public void createAlarm(String message, int hour, int minutes) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM)
            .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)
            .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hour)
            .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minutes);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```